# How to mock an instantiated class inside a function

Tags: php, unit-testing, mocking, codeception

Is there a way to test a class method that instantiates other object inside the method?

For example like below:

I want to test below without reaching the database so I want to mock this.

Is there a way to mock `myDataStoreDB` for example prior to calling `getCompetitionList` static method below so my test could pass?

```
public static function getCompetitionList($TipperID)
  {
    return self::getCompList($TipperID);
  }


private static function getCompList($TipperID, $cache=false)
  {

    $cacheOps   = Array('use' => $cache, 'expire' => 3600); 
    $view       = 'dbo.getGroupsForTipper @TipperID = ?';

    $parameters = Array(
                      0 => Array('value' => $TipperID,    'count' => 1, 'type' => myMsSql::PARAM_INT)
                      );

    $ds  = new myDataStoreDB('db', 'footy');
    $rows = $ds->get($view, $parameters, $cacheOps);

    $result = array();
    $result[] = "--Select a Competition--";
    foreach($rows as $row)
    {
      $result[$row['TippingGroupID']]['competitionName'] = $row['GroupName'];
      $result[$row['TippingGroupID']]['competitionPassword'] = $row['TGPassword'];
      $result[$row['TippingGroupID']]['competitionSportsName'] = $row['SportName'];

    }

    return $result;
 }
```

Comment: There is no. And that's why you need to inject your dependencies.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not my code...Was given a task to work with a legacy code that someone else wrote...With all legacies, it requires creativity...I'm almost now thinking of tweaking bootstrap file for the application to monkey patch myDataStoreDB for example... Would that work?